# delay "creation" of div, not just showing of div

Tags: delay, vimeo, creation, autoplay

I may not be using the proper terminology but hopefully I get my question across properly.  What I'm wondering is if it's possible to "delay" the "creation" of a specific div, rather than just delay the FadeTo or Show jquery command.

I ask because I'm using the Vimeo API which is completely mind-boggling and frustrating (at least for me - it's a source of endless shame and I wallow in self-pity when attempting any such Vimeo API coding).  What I'm trying to do is just delay the autoplay of the iframe code for an embedded Vimeo video.  The problem is that I have the div containing the vimeo iframe set to hide for a good three seconds after the page loads before it fades in, but since it's just hidden the video starts playing anyway before the visitor can actually see it.  I'm just using &autoplay=1 for the vimeo embed...

So, I suppose the only other solution besides getting this confusing Vimeo API to try to delay the video that way is to be able to just use a jQuery command to delay the vimeo iframe from even loading/being created on the page, until the container div fades in.

If this is possible I will bless my lucky charms.  And double points if someone answers in the next few hours!  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: oh and for anyone interested in my current plight with the Vimeo API and my attempt at perhaps using the API to delay the video (rather than what I am asking to be done above), here's the link to my question --> http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:51648

Love Vimeo otherwise!

Comment: Fantastic!  I eagerly await your reply!  Any assistance is appreciated 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just editted my answer and applied it to fit your code you provided:

---

So what I did here is:
 1) load jquery into your page
2)when jquery sees your div with id="div" as 'ready', it will fire an alert that says loaded (you can remove this it was just for testing purposes), and then delay the src from loading in your iframe for 2 seconds (2000 miliseconds)
3) So you can change the 2000 to whatever time you want, and make sure the "player_1" matches your iframes id

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document.getElementById('div')).ready(function() 
{
       alert('loaded');
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("player_1").src="http://www.youtube.com/v/82CYNj7noic?autoplay=1"', 2000);

 });

</script>

<div id="div" class="div">
<iframe class="iframe" id="player_1" >    </iframe>
</div>
```

​
   ​

Does this work for you?? I hope I've helped!!

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't seem to be working.  Do I put this in the <head> section?  In the iframe code in the container page do I just put src="" or do I leave src out?  And as far as style= for both the containing div and vimeo iframe why is it necessary do put this code in when I have it in my css file?  The vimeo div just isn't showing up when I add this code, so perhaps it has to go after the iframe code on the page?  Thanks!

Comment: I editted the code to match your example you provided in my other answer...just make sure that the document.getElementById("player_1") has the same name (player_1) as the id= in the iframe...also make sure your vimeo url has http:// before it,,, it didn't when u typed it before. I'm eagerly awaiting your approval!

Comment: I see how this code is supposed to run but I'm having some difficulty.  I even attempted to create a jsfiddle to teset and it's not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/p7x29/

I feel like it's something simple!  Once the jsfiddle works I can implement correctly I think!  Thanks!

Comment: Amazing!!!  THANK YOU!  Works perfect and really appreciate the help.  Once I get a 15 reputation I'll vote this answer up!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I've gotten plenty of help on StackOverflow too.

So you need points to accept answers (clicking checkmark)?

Comment: Yeah I need a 15 reputation but only have 11 as of now.  If someone upvotes one of my questions I'll get another +5 and then be able to upvote your answer (maybe you can just vote up another one of my questions)

Comment: No Problem! Ya jquery is very very useful for changing things after the page has loaded...and there's soo many different features in jquery, and you can use other people's jquery functions so it really is endless